# how to style my android 2.3 buttons?

Tags: android

is there a online tool or somehting else to simply style my android 2.3 buttons?

i dont like the layout of them and want to change it, but i dont know how without a tool.

i tryed to use holoeverywhere but this is not what i want to have.

Comment: why you don't take `GraphicalLayout` inside Eclipse with the Android ADT Plugin, that opens itself on layouts? It is getting better and better in the latest revisions.

Comment: i use this tool to ad e.g. buttons to my layout. but with this tool i can't change the style of the buttons simply

Comment: simple solution is below. You could also simply open HoloEverywhere and change bitmaps. I don't see what could be simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is great example of what you can do...

http://android.onyou.ch/2011/01/25/simple-custom-button-using-a-selector-xml-layout/

I don t understand why you should need a tool...